# Problema con "Gradle sync failed: Could not find any matches for com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.+"

Tags: android-studio, react-native, gradle

hoy por la mañana he ido a arrancar mi proyecto en react-native  y no he conseguido que me compilase para android.

me da este fallo.

"Gradle sync failed: Could not find any matches for com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.+ as no versions of com.android.tools.build:gradle are available.
            Searched in the following locations:
            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/maven-metadata.xml
            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/
            Required by:
            project :react-native-image-picker
            Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (10s 971ms)"

Llevo bastante tiempo probando cosas que he encontrado por aquí y por otros foros, pero no consigo que compile.

Os pongo el código a ver si alguien sabe que me esta pasando.

build.gradle-android

```js
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
  buildToolsVersion = "27.0.3"
  minSdkVersion = 16
  compileSdkVersion = 27
  targetSdkVersion = 26
  supportLibVersion = "27.1.1"
  googlePlayServicesVersion = "11.8.0"
  androidMapsUtilsVersion = "0.5+"
  gradle3EXPERIMENTAL = "yes"
    }
 subprojects { subproject ->
     afterEvaluate{
         if((subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android') || subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android-library'))) {
             android {
                 compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
                 buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
             }
         }
     }
 }
 
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
  google()
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
  maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
     maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}


task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.4'
    distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
}
```

build.gradle-android/app

```js
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.porfyapp"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
  multiDexEnabled true
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

configurations.all {exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-splash-screen')
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation project(':react-native-maps')
    implementation project(':react-native-image-picker')
    implementation project(':react-native-fbsdk')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
 implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.34.0'
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```

settings.gradle

```js
rootProject.name = 'myApp'
include ':react-native-splash-screen'
project(':react-native-splash-screen').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-splash-screen/android')
include ':react-native-image-picker'
project(':react-native-image-picker').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-image-picker/android')
include ':react-native-vector-icons'
project(':react-native-vector-icons').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/android')
include ':react-native-maps'
project(':react-native-maps').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-maps/Lib/android')
include ':react-native-fbsdk'
project(':react-native-fbsdk').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android')
include ':app'
```

MainApplication.java

```js
package com.myApp;

import android.app.Application;

import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import org.devio.rn.splashscreen.SplashScreenReactPackage;
import com.imagepicker.ImagePickerPackage;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.reactnative.androidsdk.FBSDKPackage;
import com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger;
import com.oblador.vectoricons.VectorIconsPackage;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;
import com.airbnb.android.react.maps.MapsPackage;
import cl.json.ShareApplication;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ShareApplication, ReactApplication {

 private static CallbackManager mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

   protected static CallbackManager getCallbackManager() {
     return mCallbackManager;
   }

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage(),
            new SplashScreenReactPackage(),
            new VectorIconsPackage(),
            new MapsPackage(),
            new ImagePickerPackage(),
   new FBSDKPackage(mCallbackManager)
      );
    }

    @Override
    protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
      return "index";
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
 AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
  }
}
```

Gracias a todos por vuestro tiempo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por alguna razón Google decidió remover los `gradle` antiguos, una solución temporal a esto es agregar estas lineas a tu archivo `build.gradle` en la carpeta de **android**, como tu, yo también utilizo la librería de `react-native-vector-icons` así que la agregué a la validación.

**android/build.gradle**

```
subprojects { subproject ->
    if (subproject.name.contains('react-native-image-picker') || subproject.name.contains('react-native-vector-icons')){
        buildscript {
            repositories {
                maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools/"  }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Esta solución la tomé de [este comentario](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-image-picker/issues/1002#issuecomment-445905528), en este [issue](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-image-picker/issues/1002) reportado en la librería

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

In \node_modules\react-native-image-picker\android\build.gradle

```
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
}
```

That works for me.

Comment: Esto no serviría si tengo un servicio automatizado que crea las builds y las sube a Play Store

Comment: En español por favor @Adria saludos!

Answer (score 0):

ha funcionado para mí:

android/build.gradle

```
subprojects { subproject ->
    if (subproject.name.contains('react-native-image-picker') || subproject.name.contains('react-native-vector-icons') || subproject.name.contains('react-native-modal-translucent')){
        buildscript {
            repositories {
                maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools/"  }
            }
        }
    }
}
```